# AWS EventBridge Scheduler shedule task on the 14th bussines day of the month

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, cron, aws-event-bridge

We've got a lambda doing so checks on files and I have to execute this lambda on a set business day every month.

I can't figure out a cron expression to do this, what would be the best way to schedule it for something like the 14th bussiness day of the month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron doesn't have a concept of "business days". I think the only way to achieve this would be to have it run every M-F and have it calculate inside the code if it is the 14th business day of the month, and if not just exit.

Comment: That's what i eventually did, thank you